# How to send audio to discord using Java Discord API?

Tags: java, discord-jda

I already know how to connect and disconnect bot to voice channel, but i can't find any method nor class in documentation that can send audio to server.

Answer (score 0):

The is a wiki on the [JDA Github page](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/4)-Making-a-Music-Bot) explaining the topic.

You might want to use [lavaplayer](https://github.com/sedmelluq/LavaPlayer#usage) which is an audio player library for Discord written in Java as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the [LavaPlayer](https://github.com/sedmelluq/lavaplayer) (Audio player library for Discord), it works fine with [JDA](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA).

> However, this is not really something for developers who have just
> started with jda, I once developed a complete Discord music bot which supported a
> multi-server queue system, he cost me at least 1 week of hard
> work. So if you have just started with jda, I would recommend you to
> try smaller or simpler tasks first.

**(But just playing a sound is not that difficult with the LavaPlayer)**